# Distribution of a random variable defined as normal with mean given by another normal random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a random variable $X\sim Binom(n, p)$, let $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$, and let $Y|X\sim Binom(\alpha X, q)$. What can be said about the distribution of $Y$? Is there any good approximation for it with a nice form?

I tried playing around with the distributions a bit but I didn't find anything nice. Any help or reference is greatly appreciated!

*Edit:* Made notation clearer.

Comment: You state in the first question that $Y$ has binomial distribution, and you state in the second question that $Y$ has normal distribution. Putting a random variable $X$ in the notation $Y$~$Binom(\alpha X,q)$ is slightly ambiguous, but you can let $Y$ equal some function of $X$ and then ask questions about $Y$'s distribution.

Comment: @robert909 Well what I want to say is that I want to have $Y$ that's distributed as drawing an observation $x$ from $X$ and then drawing $y$ from $N(q\alpha x, q(1-q)\alpha x)$. Not sure what the correct notation for that is. Then of course this is not even completely well defined, as the variance might be negative... The first question with the binomial is what interests me really, but I can settle for a good approximation.

Comment: Well, you know the distribution of $Y$ in both cases. I think you might be asking for the distribution of $Y|X$, which is a different random variable from $Y$. Are you familiar with conditional distributions?

Comment: @robert909 Right, I'm imposing $Y|X$ to be distributed as specified. Yes I know what a conditional distribution is.

Comment: @robert909 Just to be clear, I know how to write down a formula for the distribution of $Y$, but it is not a nice/clean one.